# model an abstract base class and subclasses in a database

Tags: linq-to-sql, database-design, abstract-class

I have 4 subclasses: `Video`, `Image`, `Note`, and `Form`. Each one contains different types of data. For example, the `Image` class contains a path to the image file on disk and image properties, and the `Form` class contains the form field values. The common element between each item, however, is the GPS coordinates and heading, so I have the following abstract base class:

```
public abstract class Content
{
    public float? Latitude { get; set; }
    public float? Longitude { get; set; }
    public float? Heading { get; set; }
}
```

However, where I get hazy is on how to model this in a database. Currently I have a table called `Events` (for the sake of example, let's say an event is a birthday party) and 4 tables (`Videos`, `Images`, `Notes`, and `Forms`). Each table has a foreign key linking back to `Events`' primary key.

Using LINQ-to-SQL, I get 5 classes for each table. This is fine if I only want one type of data, for example `Event.Images`, but what I want to do is count the total number of 'contents' an `Event` has and get the GPS coordinates. I can wing the count easy enough by just using `Event.Images.Count() + Event.Videos.Count() + ...`, but I can't do the same for the GPS coordinates. Is there some way I can model the database so that I can use a base class for every item and still be able to get the individual strongly-typed item when I need to see its data?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There are three different patterns for this documented in Martin Fowler's Patterns of Enterprise Application Architecture, each with different trade-offs:

- [Single Table Inheritance](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/singleTableInheritance.html)
- [Class Table Inheritance](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/classTableInheritance.html)
- [Concrete Table Inheritance](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/concreteTableInheritance.html)

Comment: Thanks for the links. They don't exactly give a good description on how to use the models, but it gives me a starting point to do more research. Personally, I've always thought that the single table model was a bad idea because it means if you add a new sub-class, you'll have to add in new columns for its data, and that can balloon to an undesirable size, though for smaller applications I can see the merits of using it.

Comment: Ya, there are definite trade-offs. It just depends on the likelihood of adding new types. If unlikely, it may be better to avoid traversing multiple tables and use the single table. If likely, one of the other patterns. And, yes, those links are pretty sparse because they want you to buy the book :-)  It's a good book - worth getting I think.

Answer (score 2):

That is one way to do it.

Generally speaking, there are two other ways:

- table per sub-class: instead of trying to share the baseclass in the database, just create separate tables for each one.
- table per hierarchy: put a superset of all the fields into a table, as well as a "discriminator" column, and store them in one place.

To figure out which is right, think about the usage patterns:

- if you generally treat them independently, and query independently, separate tables are a good way to go-- either what you have or table per subclass.
- if these are treated as heterogeneous collections, so you want to look at them as such, a single table can be easier

Also see what your tool supports most naturally. They all work.

Comment: Thanks for the response. It turns out that I need to change the entire domain model around anyway, so my problem fixed itself, so to speak.