# Saving Abstract and Sub classes to database

Tags: sql, database, linq-to-sql, entity-framework, database-design

I have an **abstract class** "**StrategyBase**", and a set of **sub classes**, **StrategyA/B/C** etc. The sub classes use some of the properties of the base class, and have some individual properties. My question is how to save this to a database.

I'm currently using SqlCE, and Linq-To-Sql by creating entity classes automatically with SqlMetal.exe.  I've seen there are three solutions shown in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1447702/model-an-abstract-base-class-and-subclasses-in-a-database), but I'm not able to see **how these solutions will work or not with SqlMetal/entity classes**. Though it seems to me the "**concrete table inheritance**" would probably work without any manual modifying. What about the other two, would they be problematic?

For "**Single Table Inheritance**" wouldn't all classes get all variables, even though they don't need them? And for the "**Class table inheritance**" solution I can't really see at all how that will map into the entity-classes for a useful purpose. I may note that I extend these partial entity classes for making the classes of my business objects.

I may also consider moving to EntityFramework instead of SqlMetal/Linq2Sql, so would be nice also to know if that makes any difference to what schema is easy to implement.

One likely important thing to note is that **I will constantly be develop new strategies**, which makes me have to modify the program code, and probably the database shcema; when adding a new strategy.

Sorry the question is a bit "all over the place", but hopefully it's some clear advantages/disadvantages here that you may be able to advice. ?

Cheers!

Comment: use TPT/TPH with Entity Framework 4. Generate the model, generate the POCO's, setup the inheritance, watch it rock and roll. Enough said.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, this exact question gets asked an awful lot, and has been [**answered many times**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4304217/database-schema-which-can-support-specialized-properties/4359193#4359193).  You probably have not searched using database terminology.

The problem is applying OO terminology and thinking in a non-object subject area; making an ordinary straight-forward task very complex and limited.

Martin Fowler's and Scott Ambler's books are not worth a dollar for the lot of them, details in [**this answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4132044/name-database-design-notation-you-prefer-and-why/4140309#4140309), starting at the **11 Dec 10** entry.

If you still have questions, post a comment.

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to make `StrategyBase` [Serializable](http://www.thescarms.com/dotnet/serializeable.aspx), then you can store it as a string in the database.  I don't know how big the string would be, as it all depends on the size of your object, but you can make the database field `nvarchar(1024)` or even `nvarchar(max)`. Ultimately this would result in the entire object being stored in a single table field as `string`.

Alternatively, as your link eludes to, you can just make a table that mimics each class, and each class object is a field in the table.